# Integration problem

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble with this integration for some reason:

$$\int\left(2\cos(2x)+2\right)^{3/2}\mathrm dx$$

Anyone know a quick and easy method to solve this?

Comment: Do you mean $\int \sqrt{2\cos(2x)+2}^2 dx$? That would be basically just $\int 2cos(2x)+2dx$

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, it was meant to say ³

Comment: If he meant the square root of the square (which is equivalent to the absolute value). In any case, $2\cos(2x)+2 \geq 0$ for all $x$ so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is `(complex-integration)`.

Comment: @GPerez What for complex integration? Even more interesting: **how** ? This is an indefinite integral.

Comment: @Timbuc I hope for a future where we come up with a different symbol and call it "antidifferentiating".

Comment: @GPerez I've been fighting for that for long years. A good place to begin with this could be this site.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that $\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta - 1$.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about basic trig identities like that.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1\implies\sqrt{1+\cos2x}=\sqrt{2\cos^2x}=\sqrt2|\cos x|$

Comment: @TedShifrin, More often than not, people take $\sqrt{x^2}=x$

Comment: @TedShifrin You both posted at almost the same time. While typing many people don't see others' answers. Not to mention the question is way too elementary to expect only one will come up with the answer.

Comment: @Timbuc: This is why I almost never answer these sorts of questions. Lesson learned.

Comment: @TedShifrin Indeed. Anyway, lab's answer reminds the OP to take absolute values off square roots. This is not "obvious" as the OP didn't remember basic trigonometric inequalities, either.